# In the full screen component, the Material Ui modal does not work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using react-full-screen node package to make a full screen component, however modals, popovers, and drawers do not work.

Could you please help me make a working modal within my full screen component?

Comment: What doesn't work? You need to give more detail!

Comment: Play around with z-index. WIth Bootstrap for example, I've never had such issue. Everything works normally with/without fullScreen. So it is a CSS thing. Or maybe a precedence issue in the order of elements in HTML (just a doubt): does your modal element come BEFORE the full-screen element in HTML? So play around with these 2

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it doesn't work ? maybe your modals are well displayed but behind your fullscreen component (did you use devtool's element inspector to check the html / css to see if your modal was here ?).
You might need to enrich your modal's css to make it visible ahead of fullscreen component, a mere `z-index: 2` on the modal' style could help ?

Comment: Although you are right, it still doesn't display over the full screen component after providing a higher zIndex value